# How to access custom Preference class from inside PreferenceFragmentCompat

Tags: android, android-preferences

I need to call a method in my custom `'android.support.v7.preference.Preference'` class.

I added the `Preferences` class like this:

`addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_prefs)`

R.xml.app_prefs:

```
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:layout="@layout/pref_category_text"
        android:title="@string/pref_category_stat_out_title">
        <com.sun.preferences.CustomPreference android:key=" @string/pref_key_show_stat" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
```

You see the the `CustomPreference` above:

It has this method `CallMee()` like this really simple I removed stuff for simplicity:

```
public class CustomPreference extends Preference {

  public CustomPreference(Context context) {
     super(context);
  }

  public void CallMee(){

  }
}
```

I have tried in the `PreferenceFragmentCompat` to use the method:

```
override fun setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser: Boolean) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser)

   if(isVisibleToUser)
     // call method CallMee() inside `CustomPreference` but how?

}
```

Since this custom `CustomPreference` is added from the `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_prefs)`

I dont understand how to call it! Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to construct an instance of your custom preference in the block of `if (isVisibleToUser)`.

Try in your PreferenceFragmentCompat subclass,

```
CustomPreference pref = findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_key_show_stat));
pref.CallMee();
```